# Discretization of differential equations, solving boundary value problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, boundary-value-problem

For $\Omega = (0,1)^2 \subseteq \mathbb R^2$ and $f \in C(\Omega)$ consider the boundary value problem:

$- \Delta u(x,y) = f(x,y)~ \forall (x,y) \in \Omega,~ 
u(x,y)=0 ~ \forall (x,y) \in \partial \Omega$

For discretization let be: $n \in \mathbb N, ~ h= \frac{1}{n+1}, ~ x_i = i \cdot h, ~ y_j = j \cdot h$ for $i,j= 0, \ldots, n+1$.

The task is to find the linear equation system for the discretized solution: $u_{i,j} = u(x_i,y_j), ~ i,j=1, \ldots, n$.

Therefore I have to deduce an approximation of $\Delta u(x_i,y_j)$, dependent on $u_{i,j},u_{i+1,j},u_{i-1,j},u_{i,j-1},u_{i,j+1}$, from taylor expansions of $u_{i-1,j},u_{i+1,j},u_{i,j-1},u_{i,j+1}$ around the point $(x_i, y_j)$ and then use the result to deduce a linear equation system for $(u_{1,1}, \ldots, u_{1,n}, u_{2,1}, \ldots, u_{2,n}, \ldots, \ldots, u_{n,1}, \ldots u_{n,n})$
where the right side is given by discretization $f_{i,j} = f(x_i, y_j)$.

Unfortunately I don't even know how to start here and would be glad for any help.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're on the right track.
\begin{align}
\Delta u(x,y) = \partial_{xx} u(x,y) + \partial_{yy} u(x,y)  
\end{align}
Now the most common way is to apply finite differences to the second derivatives, i.e.
\begin{align}
\partial_{xx} u(x_i,y_j) \approx \frac{1}{h^2}[u(x_{i-1},y_j)-2u(x_i,y_j)+u(x_{i+1},y_j)] \\
\partial_{yy} u(x_i,y_j) \approx \frac{1}{h^2}[u(x_{i},y_{j-1})-2u(x_i,y_j)+u(x_{i},y_{j+1})]
\end{align}
And your Laplacian becomes
\begin{align}
\Delta u(x_i,y_j)=\frac{1}{h^2} [u(x_{i-1},y_j)+u(x_{i+1},y_j)-4u(x_i,y_j)
+u(x_{i},y_{j-1})+u(x_{i},y_{j+1})]
\end{align}
Or by writing $u(x_i,y_j)$ as $u_{i,j}$
\begin{align}
\Delta u_{i,j}=\frac{1}{h^2} [u_{i-1,j}+u_{i+1,j}-4u_{ij}
+u_{i,j-1}+u_{i,j+1}]
\end{align}
Now do this for all $i,j$ and set up a system of linear equations $Au=f$ where $u$ contains all $(n+1)^2$ entries and $f$ the right handside. Do you know, what $A$ looks like?

Comment: I think A is the product of $\frac{1}{h^2}$ and a matrix which has the negative identity matrix on the two minor diagonals and a matrix B on the diagonal, which has "4"-entries on the diagonal and "-1"-entries on the two minor diagonals - is this correct (maybe I have to change signs)? I'm not quite sure how to use the condition $u(x,y) = 0 \forall (x,y) \in \partial \Omega$ - is this that I just put $u_{0,j}, u_{n+1,j}, u_{i,0}, u_{i,n+1} = 0$?

Comment: The i-th row looks somewhat like $\frac1h^2[0,..,0,1,0,..,0,1,-4,1,0..,0,1,0,..,0]$. If that's what you're meaning, you're correct! The dimension of $A$ is $n^2\times n^2$. For the boundary nodes, you would set the corresponding entries in $f$ to zero.